# Pycharm keeps asking for authentication token

Tags: pycharm

In Pycharm, when I run a cell, I keep getting a request to enter the authentication token.

How can I get Pycharm to launch a new server for this notebook?

I'd like it to also use a particular Anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my interpreter settings were invalid.  For Mac, go to Preferences/Project/Project Interpreter and make sure your interpreter is not marked 'invalid'.